# Alternating Text in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```css
/*Vertical Flip*/

.verticalFlip {
  display: inline;
}

.verticalFlip span {
  animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #ea1534;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* text */

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: rgb(1, 16, 231);
  color: white;
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Sample
    <div class="verticalflip"><span>Change</span><span>Text</span></h1>
</section>
```

I would like the text to be `Sample Change` and the `Change` alternates to `Text`. Right now, the text is not alternating and its on a new line whereas I would like it to be all on one line and the `Sample` text does not change (remains constant) but there should be a vertical flip word change on the `Change` and it should alternate between `Text`. How can I accomplish this?

This is where I got the code from: https://codepen.io/kaceyatstandcreative/pen/PowbpKm

Comment: You have kept quite a lot of the original in your code. You want to alternate between two words, the code was originally set up to alternate between 5 words. Start by going through removing all the obviously redundant stuff (like nth-child(3) etc). Then think about the timings and the actual keyframes that you need to cope with just two words.

Answer (score 2):

First, there are some errors in your code:

1. In HTML, you're missing the `</div>`.
2. Typo at class="`verticalflip`" should be `verticalFlip` as indicated in your css
3. Multiple `color` properties in a single css `#hero h1` block

After fixing those errors, your animation doesn't appear because the `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` removes any text color. You should change it into `color: transparent;` in your case.

**Updated:**

1. change text to background image
2. remove delay between text by remove other span dependencies.

```css
/*Vertical Flip*/

.verticalFlip {
  display: inline;
}

.verticalFlip span {
  animation: vertical 4s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: vertical 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 4s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-position: 15% 20%;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* text */

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: transparent;
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Sample
    <div class="verticalFlip"><span>Change</span><span>Text</span></div></h1>
</section>
```

Comment: how would you have the same background of `Sample` on `Text` too?

Comment: You can yet add another `background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg");` and `background-clip: text;` into the `.verticalFlip span` block. And may change position via `background-position`.

Comment: also there is a delay. I want to remove that delay, how can I do that? can you edit your post to do that? I will validate your answer after that

Comment: like there is a long delay when the texts get alternated. I want it to be instant where it keeps alternating text without any pause

Comment: And remember to remove the `color: #ea1534;` or change it to `color: transparent;` in case it overrides your text background.

Comment: could you edit with the changes please?

Comment: I made the changes, please take a look.

Comment: hmm the code broke

Comment: the code broke when you made the changes

Comment: I edited the answer. The problem might be an older browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

You had some broken HTML, so I fixed that. Also replaced the spans with div because `transform: rotate` only works with block elements, not inline elements like `span`.

I animated, just by spinning the text, and not changing the opacity. I will leave that up to you if you want to add that. I also added a pause where the text isn't animated (looping from 90% to 10% with 0deg rotation).

In order to get all elements on the same row, I added `display: flex` to your `h1`, and to make the spinning text to overlay I was forced to use a grid layout, where both children are on row 1 and column 1 (`grid-area`). I tried `position: absolute` but `background-clip: text` didn't work on Firefox when I did that.

I increased the font size in order to show the background-clip in a better way.

[edit] Apparently, Chrome bugs out when using `background-clip: text` together with `backface-visibility: hidden`.

### Working example: Firefox

```css
#hero > h1 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;

  font-size: 78px;
  font-weight: 700;

  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

.verticalflip {
  display: grid;
}

.verticalflip > div {
  --animation-duration: 6s;

  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  animation: vertical var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.verticalflip > div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: calc(-0.5 * var(--animation-duration));
}

@keyframes vertical {
  10%  { transform: rotateX(0deg);   }
  40%  { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
  60%  { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
  90%  { transform: rotateX(0deg);   }
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="">
    <div>Sample&nbsp;</div>
    
    <div class="verticalflip">
      <div>Change</div>
      <div>Text</div>
    </div>
  </h1>
</section>
```

### Working example: Chrome & Safari

```css
#hero > h1 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;

  font-size: 78px;
  font-weight: 700;

  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

#hero div {
  /* Chrome somehow "looses" the background when animating it */
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.verticalflip {
  display: grid;
}

.verticalflip > div {
  --animation-duration: 6s;

  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  animation: vertical var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.verticalflip > div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: calc(-0.5 * var(--animation-duration));
}

@keyframes vertical {
  10%  { transform: rotateX(0deg);   }
  40%  { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
  60%  { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
  90%  { transform: rotateX(0deg);   }
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="">
    <div>Sample&nbsp;</div>
    
    <div class="verticalflip">
      <div>Change</div>
      <div>Text</div>
    </div>
  </h1>
</section>
```

Comment: the code doesnt work

Comment: Don't use properties that aren't fully supported then. It works as intended on Firefox but bugs out on Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#hero > h1 {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;

  font-size: 78px;
  font-weight: 700;

  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

#hero div {
  /* Chrome somehow "looses" the background when animating it */
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.verticalflip {
  display: grid;
}

.verticalflip > div {
  --animation-duration: 6s;

  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  animation: vertical var(--animation-duration) linear infinite;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.verticalflip > div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: calc(-0.5 * var(--animation-duration));
}

@keyframes vertical {
  10%  { transform: rotateX(0deg);   }
  40%  { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
  60%  { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
  90%  { transform: rotateX(0deg);   }
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="">
    <div>Sample&nbsp;</div>
    
    <div class="verticalflip">
      <div>Change</div>
      <div>Text</div>
    </div>
  </h1>
</section>
```